# Problema con dominio gmail.com cuando uso Esquema html en mensaje mail

Tags: php, mail

En el siguiente código estoy recopilado datos de un formulario y estoy enviando mensajes con mail con PHP, funciona bien mientras el mensaje sea normal, pero cuando agrego un formato HTML y el correo que recopilo del formulario tiene el @gmail.com no envía el mensaje, pero si pongo cualquier otra cosa como @adgsd.adsf, @dsg.dfgr si envía el correo, solo pasa cuando pongo el HTML en el mensaje, por que no envía cuando uso HTML en el mensaje?

```
<?php
        // include(__DIR__.'/C_form.php');
        
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
            if(isset($_POST['nombreParra'])){
                $nombre=$_POST['nombreParra'];
                $correo=$_POST['emailParra'];
                $asunto=$_POST['asuntoParra'];
                $mensaje=$_POST['mensajeParra'];
                $sede="Sede Parra";
            } else if(isset($_POST['nombreGrau'])){
                $nombre=$_POST['nombreGrau'];
                $correo=$_POST['emailGrau'];
                $asunto=$_POST['asuntoGrau'];
                $mensaje=$_POST['mensajeGrau'];
                $sede="Sede Grau";
            }
    
            $to="rrhh@aprsupport.net";
            $subject= $sede . ": " . $asunto;
            $message= 'Nombre: '."$nombre\n".'Correo: '."$correo\n"."$sede\n".'Mensaje: '. "$mensaje";
            $header='From: '. $correo;
    
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
        }

        // if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        //     if(isset($_POST['nombre1'])){
        //         $nombre=$_POST['nombre1'];
        //         $celular=$_POST['celular1'];
        //         $correo=$_POST['email1'];
        //         $asunto=$_POST['asunto1'];
        //         $mensaje=$_POST['mensaje1'];
        //         $sede="Sede Parra";
        //     } else if(isset($_POST['nombre2'])){
        //         $nombre=$_POST['nombre2'];
        //         $celular=$_POST['celular2'];
        //         $correo=$_POST['email2'];
        //         $asunto=$_POST['asunto2'];
        //         $mensaje=$_POST['mensaje2'];
        //         $sede="Sede Grau";
        //     }
        
        //     $to="rrhh@aprsupport.net";
        //     $subject= $sede.": ". $asunto;
        
        //     $message = '<html>
        //                     <body>
        //                         <div style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; background-color: #f4f4f4; box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        //                             <div style="max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; background-color: #fff; border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);">
        //                                 <div class="titulo" style="padding: 15px;background-color: red; border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;">
        //                                     <h2 style="color: #fff">' . $subject . '</h2>
        //                                 </div>
        //                                 <div class="cuerpo" style="padding: 15px;background-color: #ffffff; border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;">
        //                                     <p><strong>Nombre:</strong> ' . $nombre . '</p>
        //                                     <p><strong>Celular:</strong> ' . $celular . '</p>
        //                                     <p><strong>Correo:</strong> ' . $correo . '</p>
        //                                     <p><strong>Sede:</strong> ' . $sede . '</p>
        //                                     <p><strong>Mensaje:</strong> ' . $mensaje . '</p>
        //                                 <div class="botonCorreo" style="text-align: center;">
        //                                     <a href="mailto:' . $correo . '" style="border-radius: 5px; background-color: red; color: white; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; padding: 10px 15px;">Responder al correo</a>
        //                                     <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=51'. $celular .'"  style="border-radius: 5px; background-color: red; color: white; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; padding: 10px 15px;">Responder por Whatsapp</a>
        //                                     </div>
        //                                 </div>
        //                             </div>
        //                         </div>
        //                     </body>
        //                 </html>';
        
        //     $headers = array();
        //     $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
        //     $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8';
        //     $headers[] = 'From: ' . $correo;
        
        //     $header = implode("\r\n", $headers);
        //     mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
        //}
    ?>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no se envia?? o llega a spam?? o llega rechazado???

Comment: No aparece, como si no se hubiera enviado, pero cuando pongo @gmail.com sin el html en el mensaje si llega

Comment: bueno en algun lado hay un error.. verifica que no tengas errores en tu servidor smtp

Comment: Intenta con [PHPmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: Hola @BrayanAquinoVillanueva. El problema es lógico, vos no podes enviar desde (`from`) cuentas que NO estan hosteadas en ese servidor. Te estaras haciendo pasar por alguien que no sos, esto es considerado SPAM y algunas veces directamente el mail entrante o saliente es filtrado por tu propio mailserver. Lo normal es que el mail salgo desde (`from`) una cuenta `@tudominio` y utilices el encabezado `Reply-to` para poner la cuenta del contacto/cliente.

Comment: @Marcos y eso solo es con PHPmail?? Lo pregunto porque yo cuando uso PHPmailer, utilizo alguna cuenta de Google para enviar mis correos, no necesariamente de "mi dominio". Es más, en mi ambiente de pruebas yo uso uno de mis Gmail personales.

Comment: @OCHOA si te conectas a la cuenta usando SMTP o POP3, no vas a tener ningún problema ya que te has autenticado en el dominio para enviar desde tu cuenta. El problema en este caso es que el OP utiliza la función `mail` la que generalmente utiliza el mailserver de servidor donde host-ea su sistema.

Comment: Si quitas los elementos `<a>` ¿funciona?