# El envio de un correo con mail() de PHP no funciona

Tags: php

Bueno en  primer lugar utilizo web node como el proveedor de mi correo para el el destinatario de los correos.
Tengo un formulario:

```
<form method="post">
                        <div class="row g-3">
                            <div class="col-md-6" style="height: 55px;">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control border-0 bg-light px-4" placeholder="Nombres" id="nombreParra" name="nombreParra" style="height: 55px; margin-bottom: 0;" oninput="validarNombre('nombreParra', 'validacionNombreParra')" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6" style="height: 55px;">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control border-0 bg-light px-4" placeholder="Celular" id="celularParra" name="celularParra" style="height: 55px; margin-bottom: 0;" oninput="validarCelular('celularParra','validacionCelularParra')" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <p id="validacionNombreParra"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <p id="validacionCelularParra"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control border-0 bg-light px-4" placeholder="Email" id="emailParra" name="emailParra" style="height: 55px; margin-bottom: 0;" oninput="validarCorreo('emailParra','validacionEmailParra')" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p id="validacionEmailParra"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control border-0 bg-light px-4" placeholder="Asunto" id="asuntoParra" name="asuntoParra" style="height: 55px; margin-bottom: 0;" oninput="validarAsunto('asuntoParra','validacionAsuntoParra')" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p id="validacionAsuntoParra"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <textarea class="form-control border-0 bg-light px-4 py-3" rows="4" placeholder="Mensaje" id="mensajeParra" name="mensajeParra" style="margin-bottom: 0;" oninput="validarMensaje('mensajeParra','validacionMesajeParra')" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p id="validacionMensajeParra"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary w-100 py-3 " type="submit">Enviar Mensaje</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Donde la finalidad es simple de capturar datos y enviarlos a un correo con dicho controlador en PHP:

```
<?php
    // include(__DIR__.'/C_form.php');
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        if(isset($_POST['nombreParra'])){
            $nombre=$_POST['nombreParra'];
            $celular=$_POST['celularParra'];
            $correo=$_POST['emailParra'];
            $asunto=$_POST['asuntoParra'];
            $mensaje=$_POST['mensajeParra'];
            $sede="Sede Parra";
        } else if(isset($_POST['nombreGrau'])){
            $nombre=$_POST['nombreGrau'];
            $celular=$_POST['celularGrau'];
            $correo=$_POST['emailGrau'];
            $asunto=$_POST['asuntoGrau'];
            $mensaje=$_POST['mensajeGrau'];
            $sede="Sede Grau";
        }

        $to="rrhh@aprsupport.net";
        $subject= $sede . ": " . $asunto;
        $message= '<html>
                        <body>
                            <div style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; background-color: #f4f4f4; box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                                <div style="max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; background-color: #fff; border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);">
                                    <div class="titulo" style="padding: 15px;background-color: red; border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;">
                                        <h2 style="color: #fff">' . $subject . '</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="cuerpo" style="padding: 15px;background-color: #ffffff; border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;">
                                        <p><strong>Nombre:</strong> ' . $nombre . '</p>
                                        <p><strong>Celular:</strong> ' . $celular . '</p>
                                        <p><strong>Correo:</strong> ' . $correo . '</p>
                                        <p><strong>Sede:</strong> ' . $sede . '</p>
                                        <p><strong>Mensaje:</strong> ' . $mensaje . '</p>
                                    <div class="botonCorreo" style="text-align: center;">
                                        <a href="mailto:' . $correo . '" style="border-radius: 5px; background-color: red; color: white; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; padding: 10px 15px;">Responder al correo</a>
                                        <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=51'. $celular .'"  style="border-radius: 5px; background-color: red; color: white; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; padding: 10px 15px;">Responder por Whatsapp</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </body>
                    </html>';
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8';
    $headers[] = 'From: ' .$nombre;
   

    $header = implode("\r\n", $headers);
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
    }
    
?>
```

El problema que tengo es en el campo donde tiene que ingresar el correo al colocar alguno que tenga **@gmail** este no es enviado , lo peculiar de esto es que si en la estructura del mensaje quito la estructura HTML y solo coloco cualquier texto en plano o variable este envía normal al destinatario y que la cabecera tenga dicho correo con **@gmail.com** pero en caso que desee utilizar una estructura HTML en el mensaje tengo que cambiar que en el **"Form:"** no tenga la variable del correo y que no almacene alguno que tenga **@gmail.com**

Comment: Parece la [misma pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/613040/problema-con-dominio-gmail-com-cuando-uso-esquema-html-en-mensaje-mail).

Comment: Si realice la misma consulta en otra ocasión

Comment: ¿Cuantas cuentas tenes? Cuando decis _"[...] en otra ocación"_ suena que fue hace mucho y en realidad fue hace menos de 24hs. Si podes, revisa los comentarios que te dejamos en la otra pregunta.